# Flickering ScrollBar on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, flicker

I'm refreshing data on DataGridView on every second, it was previously flickering, but I worked it out by using double buffering, however the scrollbar that is by default atached to the DataGridView is still flickering, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing? Mind posting some code?

Comment: Have you tried to put the refresh code inside a `SuspendLayout() - ResumeLayout()` block?

Comment: All I do is changing and sorting elements in BindingList that is bounded to the DataGridView, and calling ResetBaindings() and also updating the selected row after sorting.

Comment: In the refreshing code I hade at the beginning `DataGridView.Enabled=false` and at the end `DataGridView.Enabled=true` and that cause the problem.